# SQL filtering query; how do include something for one country (France) but not the others (selected European countries)

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have 5 countries and some of their industries in a table called country_data

**Country** field:
Portugal,
France,
Italy,
Germany,
Spain

**Industry** field:
Wine, 
Cheese,
Beer

But I only want to include 'Cheese' for France. How do I filter it out for the other countries while still including it for France?

I'm trying to use CASE but it's not working as planned

Thanks

```
SELECT country, 
       industry
FROM country_data
WHERE (

    industry = 'Wine' OR
    industry = 'Beer' OR
    CASE WHEN country = 'France' THEN industry = 'Cheese' ELSE null 
    END

)
```

The expected result would be Wine and Beer for all countries, but only Cheese for France

Comment: What do you mean by: ".. include 'Cheese' for France". ? Are `Countries` and `Industries` tables ? The Case statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: update your question and add  a  clear data sample /(not juts  a list of separated  value)  .. and  the expected  result

Comment: I think your query should work, although it's simpler to write `WHERE industry in ('Wine', 'Beer') OR (country = 'France' AND industry = 'Cheese')`

Comment: Apologies - 'country' and 'industry' are fields, coming from the country_data table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Barmar helped me with this answer.

```
SELECT country, 
       industry
FROM country_data
WHERE (

    industry = 'Wine' OR
    industry = 'Beer' OR
    (country = 'France' and industry = 'Cheese')

)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different conditions and they must be combined with OR:

```
SELECT 
  country, 
  industry
FROM country_data
WHERE 
  country = 'France' 
  OR
  (country <> 'France' AND industry <> 'Cheese')
```

or the equivalent:

```
SELECT 
  country, 
  industry
FROM country_data
WHERE 
  country = 'France' OR industry <> 'Cheese'
```